# Propel unsets primary key when saved twice

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

Consider we have the following model class `Model` generated by Propel. Furthermore we use the  sfPropelORMPlugin to generate forms and filters.

We create a `Model` instance using `ModelForm` as follows.

```
$form = new ModelForm();
$form->getObject()->save();
// first var_dump
var_dump($form->getObject()->getId());
$form->bind(array(), array());

$form->save();
// second var_dump
var_dump($form->getObject()->getId()); exit();
```

Running a simple unit test will for example give the following result.

```
int(100) // say the auto_increment value of the PK starts at 100
NULL
```

Why does the second var_dump return NULL? Is this desired behaviour? Or is this a bug in either Propel or sfPropelORMPlugin?

The issue exists with at least Propel version 1.7.0 .

Comment: I don't work with Symfony, but my guess is that the `->getObject()` call creates a new Propel entity, thus the empty `Id` as it would be set upon saving.

Comment: Well the object is created in the constructor. Maybe this has something to do with sfFormPropel::isNew().

Comment: What does the first `var_dump()` call return?